# Get the values for all the input hidden in the html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a list with the values for all of the input hidden that I have in my HTML. All of these inputs hidden ids will end with the string `LevelName`. This is an example of the inputs (they don't have to appear one after another):

```
<input id="VariableDataList_0__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[0].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_1" />
<input id="VariableDataList_1__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[1].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_2" />
<input id="VariableDataList_2__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[2].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_3" />
```

I have tried this:

```
console.log($( this ).find("input:hidden[id$='LevelName']"));
```

And on the console I get:

```
[object Object]{0: HTMLInputElement {...}, 1: HTMLInputElement {...}, 2: HTMLInputElement {...}, context: HTMLDocument {...}, jquery: "2.1.1", length: 3, prevObject: Object {...}, selector: "input:hidde..."}
```

I have also tried:

```
console.log($( this ).find("input:hidden[id$='LevelName']").val());
```

But I get:

```
nivel_1
```

I think I'm on the right way but I don't know how to get all the values from the result of find.

How can I get all the values in one string separared by commas?

Comment: loop through the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not looping throught the collection of inputs, you are just returning the value of the first one.

You need to use `$("input[id$='LevelName'][type='hidden']")` to get all the `hidden` inputs and then use `.each()`method to loop over them to take their values:

**Demo:**

```js
$("input[id$='LevelName'][type='hidden']").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="VariableDataList_0__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[0].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_1" />
<input id="VariableDataList_1__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[1].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_2" />
<input id="VariableDataList_2__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[2].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var allvalues = $("input:hidden[id$='LevelName']").map(function() {
  return $(this).val()
}).get()
console.log(allvalues)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="VariableDataList_0__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[0].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_1" />
<input id="VariableDataList_1__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[1].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_2" />
<input id="VariableDataList_2__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[2].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_3" />
```

1. Loop all the inputs.
2. use .map() to get the input values and put it in array

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through all elements and then get the value.

```js
$("input:hidden[id$='LevelName']").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="VariableDataList_0__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[0].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_1" />
<input id="VariableDataList_1__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[1].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_2" />
<input id="VariableDataList_2__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[2].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the element .so Try with [`each()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiuxLaekvnTAhXJs48KHVi-DAcQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Feach%2F&usg=AFQjCNERiS3iAZ_VNLBSp22Y5a_-bQPP3w&sig2=JM6PraZVZcKptwf5qQxkwg)

```js
$("input:hidden[id$='LevelName']").each(function(){
console.log($( this ).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="VariableDataList_0__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[0].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_1" />
<input id="VariableDataList_1__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[1].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_2" />
<input id="VariableDataList_2__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[2].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because when you call `val()` on a jQuery object holding a collection of elements it will only return the value of the first one in the set.

If you want to build a list of the values you can create an array of them using `map()`, like this:

```js
var values = $("input:hidden[id$='LevelName']").map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="VariableDataList_0__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[0].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_1" />
<input id="VariableDataList_1__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[1].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_2" />
<input id="VariableDataList_2__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[2].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the input fields.

```js
$("input").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="VariableDataList_0__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[0].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_1" />
<input id="VariableDataList_1__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[1].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_2" />
<input id="VariableDataList_2__LevelName" name="VariableDataList[2].LevelName" type="hidden" value="nivel_3" />
```